# Cloudwatch logs - No Event Data after time elapses

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I've looked on the [AWS forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=223930) and elsewhere but haven't found a solution. I have a lambda function that, when invoked, creates a log stream which populates with log events. After about 12 hours or so, the log stream is still present, but when I open it, I see the following:

[image: No Event Data]

The link explains how to start sending event data, but I already have this set up, and I am sending event data, it just disappears after a certain time period.

I'm guessing there is some setting somewhere (either for max storage allowed or for whether logs get purged), but if there is, I haven't found it.

Comment: Is this a free tier?

Comment: No, not a free tier, but worth asking!

Comment: What happens when you select the date to 27 July in the filter?

Comment: Good thought...that's for filtering many log events within a single log stream. My heart skipped a beat though when you asked about it.

Comment: So does it show the events for 27 July?

Comment: Not quite. There's a drop-down menu that's not in the screenshot that allows you to select various log streams. Within a single log stream there may be many log events, some with different dates. The Date/Time shown in the screenshot is for filtering the events within the selected stream.

Comment: Check this thread some what similar to your case https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=223930

Comment: Yea, I linked that above...I'll make it more prominent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR:  Just use the CLI. See Update 2 below.

---

This is really bizarre but I can replicate it...

[image]

I un-checked the "Expire Events After" box, and lo and behold I was able to open older log streams. What seems REALLY odd is that if I choose to display the "Stored Bytes" data, many of the files are listed at 0 bytes even though they have log events:

[image: 7/29/2016 CloudWatch Log Streams]

Update 1:

This solution no longer works as I can only view the log events in the first two log streams. What's more is that the Stored Bytes column displays different (and more accurate) data:

[image: 8/01/2016 CloudWatch Log Streams]

This leads me to believe that AWS made some kind of update.

UPDATE 2:

Just use the CLI. I've verified that I can retrieve log events from the CLI that I cannot retrieve via the web console.

First install the CLI (if you haven't already) and use the following command:

`aws logs get-log-events --log-group-name NAME-OF-LOGGROUP --log-stream-name LOG-STREAM-NAME     // be sure to escape special characters such as /, [, $ etc`

Comment: Last days (29/30) seemed to be quite problematic. I had a friend asking for help because he couldn't log into his account - He did reset the password & regained access. However, all his instances were gone, and billing didn't report any costs. Yet, all his infra seemed to be running OK because he could connect via SSH/RDP/HTTP(s). It looked like the instances were just disassociated from his account. Apart from that, we got various HTTP 500 when trying to access the dashboard. Everything seemed to be working fine via CLI though.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason for missing data in the log stream might be a corrupted agent-state file. First check your logs

```
vim /var/log/awslogs.log
```

If you find something like "Caught exception: An error occurred (InvalidSequenceTokenException) when calling the PutLogEvents operation: The given sequenceToken is invalid. The next expected sequenceToken is:" you can regenerate the agent-state file as follows:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/awslogs/agent-state
sudo service awslogs stop
sudo service awslogs start
```